# Push PHP Variable to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to push a php variable to javascript. The code is below but does not seem to work. Can anyone show me how to do this?

```
ticks.push(<?php echo json_encode($new); ?>);
```

Comment: What does the `echo json_encode($new);` produce? What's the resulting line of javascript?

Comment: Also, does json_last_error() return anything?

Comment: i want to add the string present in $new to next element of tick array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ticks.push(JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($new); ?>'));
```

Or broken down:

```
var json = '<?= json_encode($new); ?>';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
ticks.push(obj)
```

also addressed in this issue:

[Accessing an array in PHP from Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688248/accessing-an-array-in-php-from-javascript-jquery/29688536#29688536)

Answer (score -1):

can you try this

```
var tricks = [
<?php 
    foreach ($new as $n) {
        echo '"'.$n'", ';
    }
?>
];
```

Comment: There's so much "wrong" with your suggestion, that I just don't know where to start from...

Answer (score -2):

you can use websocket to do such like functionality; in it you can send the result back to the client from the php code when it is ready one good example on that is how stackoverflow notify you when there is new question, or when they notify you if the post is edited.